# Issue with OOTB publishing Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

Yesterday I encounter a strange issue on **SharePoint 2013** site

I have a simple list with basic columns like Title, description, thumbnail (url of picture to displayed) on which a simple ***OOTB publishing workflow*** attached to it.

I have 15 Approved items in a list & they are visible on my home page as web part but yesterday   the publishing workflow resets itself & the home page web part shows no item in it. And workflow status column shows nothing in it.

In such case I have to start manually workflow on each item & getit approved from admin privilege.
This issue happens occur on both production as well as my test environment.

Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is Resolved

The cause for the mentioned issue  was due to the default timer job **“Workflow Auto Cleanup”** which is associated to each web application in SharePoint.

his job deletes tasks and workflow instances which have been marked complete longer than the expiration specified in the workflow association, often set at 60 days.

http://www.sharepoint2013.me/Blog/Post/221/Manage-workflow-settings-for-SharePoint-web-applications